# errno 2: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I've seen multiple threads with this issue but I can't find one that applies to my situation. I'm using a library called audiodiff that essentially tells you whether or not two audio files have the same content. I have recorded 2 .wav files previously saved that I want to check. Here is the code:

```
import audiodiff
print audiodiff.audio_equal('output1.wav', 'output2.wav', ffmpeg_bin=None)
```

Here is the output I'm getting in the terminal when I run it:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/audiodiff/__init__.py", line 51, in audio_equal
return checksum(name1, ffmpeg_bin) == checksum(name2, ffmpeg_bin)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/audiodiff/__init__.py", line 86, in checksum
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
```

The explanations I've seen on here have something to do with the cd, but all of my files are in the same folder. So, I'm not sure how that applies. Any insight on this would be awesome. TIA.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the script from the directory containing both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make absolute paths to the files using Python's `os.path` tools:

```
 import os

 fname = os.path.join(path_to_output1, 'output1.wav')
```

If you need to grab the path at the start of the application, before you do any change directory you can do it:

```
path = os.getcwd()  # Get the current path where the application was started
```

Without knowing your full source code, directory layout and exact program invocation it is difficult to say more.

More info:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html?highlight=path#module-os.path

Comment: Those two lines of code is literally all the code. Just one .py file with 2 two .wav files in the same directory. I am not sure if i need to take into account where the library that I am using is stored or not.

Comment: I think the issue is that it doesn't find your ffmpeg binaries, not that it doesn't find your audio files.

Comment: That makes sense. How does one configure that? meaning how do I tell it where to find the ffmpeg binaries?

Comment: Give full path to `ffmpeg` binary, on your hard disk, in `ffmpeg_bin` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the dependencies for audiodiff?

> audiodiff requires FFmpeg to be installed in your system. The path is ffmpeg by default, but you can change it by following ways (later rules take precedence over earlier ones).
>
> 1. audiodiff.FFMPEG_BIN module property
> 2. FFMPEG_BIN environment variable
> 3. ffmpeg_bin flag (commandline tool only)